# Spark process never ends when insert into Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I trying to append some rows (5 million rows/ 2800 columns) in a Hive table through Spark/Scala, but the process seems to stuck after long hours. The logs don't show any errors.

How can I be sure the process is really running?
Is there something to do to optimize the job?

My submit configs:

--driver-memory 15 G
--executor-memory 30g 
--num-executors 35
--executor-cores 5

Thanks!

---

```
 def exprToAppend(myCols: Set[String], allCols: Set[String]) = {
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
allCols.toList.map(x => x match {
case x if myCols.contains(x) => col(x)
case _ => lit(0d).as(x)
})
}


val insert : DataFrame = tableFinal.select(exprToAppend(tableFinal.columns.toSet, historico.columns.toSet):_ *).select(historico.columns.map(x => col(x)) :_*);

insert.write.mode("append")
.format("parquet")
.insertInto(s"${Configuration.SIGLA}${Configuration.TABLE_HIST}")
```

Comment: Are you using YARN?

Comment: @Greg Yes, I am using Yarn.

Comment: Please check executor thread dump from SparkUI and see it might be printing some logs. Also check  spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled property is true or false. Try to disable.